# PLIVO SMS Sender Id Issue

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send SMS to indian numbers using plivo Api. I have set src as sender number (9185623XXXXX).

obj.src = "9185623XXXXX";

But all my sms's are getting received as "VM-PLVS". How to enable sending sms as sender number. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

Due to the Telecom Regulations in India, it is not possible to set any number as the Sender ID while sending a message. However, you can send SMS to Indian numbers using an Alphanumeric Sender ID like HAPPYY. Please reach out to our [support team](https://support.plivo.com/) to get a Sender ID registered.

Answer (score 2):

In India, SMS gateway providers usually replaces your `src/from` number to their default sms short code while sending out. This comes under promotional and transactional sms. Refer [link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-promotional-SMS-vs-transactional-SMS)

You should opt for long code sms and a DID number (valid From number from sms gateway provider) to set a proper 10 digit number as `From` number and to get reply back.

There is no possibility of setting a dynamic `From/src` number in SMS gateway provider in india, like you do in VOIP calling.

To conclude this is not an issues with your nodeJS application. Call/Email Plivo team to get few clarity on this.